# how to convert d3.html result into element to append?

Tags: d3.js

The d3.html return is an html fragment of nested divs. d3.insert/append requires a node I believe. How do I get d3.append to take d3.html result as input? tia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (and you don't need to). You can simply do

```
d3.html("foo", function(fragment) {
  parentElement.node().appendChild(fragment);
});
```

Oh and keep in mind that `d3.html` doesn't return anything -- it's an asynchronous function and the result is passed to the callback.

Comment: following the above (I think): d3.html('data/view1a.html', function(fragment) {
    d3.select(".containerDebug").html(fragment);
}); with "<div>TEST FRAGMENT</div>" as the file text, prints "[object DocumentFragment]" in the div. Can I script a div like this and bring it in? I think I can so I have missed something. tia (how does one put code in the comment box?)

Comment: Ah sorry, you can't actually append DocumentFragments like that -- I've updated the answer; the code should work now.

Comment: turns out it is erroring - I had hard-coded div text for quick test and that was what I saw ..... error is Uncaught TypeError: d3.select(...).node(...).append is not a function .... d3.select(".containerDebug").node().append(fragment); and div does exist.

Comment: got it thanks for the help - can drive one crazy switching between  the two